# Excluding resources from maven dependencies while exporting project to jar

Tags: java, maven

I have two local maven projects `A`, and `B`. `B` is dependent on `A`.

```
A
|- resources/log4j2.xml

B
|- resources/META-INF/log4j.xml
|- Maven Dependencies
    |- A
    |- And other dependencies...
```

Both `A`, and `B` exports the `log4j` xmls to jar. However, as I only need the `B/resources/META-INF/log4j.xml` to my final `B.jar`, I tried to delete the `log4j2.xml` from `A` while packing `B.jar`.

To do the same, I used [truezip:remove](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/remove-mojo.html) in `B/pom.xml` as follows:

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>remove-a-file-in-sub-archive</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>remove</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>B-jar-with-dependencies.jar</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
...
</build>
```

Note that this is executed `verify` state (post packaging) of lifecycle.

Though it is working as expected, I am wondering whether there is any side-effect of this or not. Any light in this regard would be great.